# A word similar to handicap/slack

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

I'll start off with an example for context.

Two race car drivers race for the fastest lap time on track X in identical cars. Racer A finishes before Racer B, however it was discovered afterwards that Racer B had a faulty transmission, decreasing his acceleration compared to Racer A. Therefore, it would be reasonable to assume they would have finished at the same time if the transmission from Racer B was functioning properly.

In this case, what non-tangible word would you associate with Racer B? Similar to "cutting him slack", or his "transmission handicap". We would give him ***_*_**. I was just thinking about this word yesterday, and today it completely slipped my mind. I believe it starts with "com-", but I'm not entirely sure. Help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just remembered: compensation

Comment: Your edit should be an answer, and you should accept it.   Unless you're hoping for ...?

Answer (score 1):

Give the guy a break.

Or in your Nascar example, (and I hope I'm not going to far out for the pun) a "brake."

Comment: NASCAR is an acronym.  Hey, what do you know, a 'right answer'.   If you hate it so much here, why don't you make a proper name and settle in?